# golang html.Node.Data container no human characters

Tags: html, go, web

i've copied the code below from go programming language book but my output is not the same as in the book
the code is as follows :

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)


func main() {
    doc , err := html.Parse(os.Stdin)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "findlinks1: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    for _ , link := range visit([]string{} ,doc)  {
        fmt.Println(link);
    }

    

}

func visit(links []string , n *html.Node) []string {
    

        if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "a"{
            for _,a := range n.Attr {
                if a.Key == "href" {
                    links = append(links , a.Val)
                }
            }
        }

        for c := n.FirstChild ; c != nil ; c = c.NextSibling {
                visit(links,c)
        }
    return links 
}
```

the data obtained from stdin is in fact the output of another prog that brings the html of a web page the image below shows its output:
[image]
i've added a printf at the begining of visit to see what's going on but i found out that n.Data contains no tag name instead it contains a branch of unreadable characters
any help ???

Comment: Since you are reading from stdin, it highly depends on what you pass to your program from stdin. Without this information, it's not really possible to reason about your programs behaviour.

Comment: now you can see the input

Answer (score 0):

this program doesn't work because the links variable is copied during the function visit it's true that this new copy points to the same underlying array but any changes assign to it doesn't affect the original so at line

```
visit(links,c) must be links = visit(links,c)
```